# QGIS 3.4 changing feature attributes

Tags: qgis

I am using QGIS 3.4 and I have unintentionally labelled two lakes with the same name as they are listed as one feature in the attribute table. I cannot figure out how to change the feature attribute for one of them so that they are separated.

Any suggestions, or do I have to redraw these areas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you have a multipart polygon, made by the polygons of the two lakes.
You just need to separate the two polygons, this will result into two independent features, which you can label separately.

In QGIS you need to install the [Digitizing Tools](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/DigitizingTools/) plugin. 
Then make the layer editable (using the pencil icon), select the multipart feature (the lakes) and click the `Split multi part to single part` icon, in the `Digitizing tool` ribbon. 
To save, toggle the pencil icon.

Alternatively use the [Multipart Split](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/splitmultipart/) plugin.